# Where is wpath in VS2015

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, c++14, c++17

Just upgraded to VS 2015 (from VS 2013).
Tried to compile my projects but `wpath` (which I use a LOT!) is not recognized. 
Open the `filesystem` file:

`...Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\filesystem`

compare it with:

`...Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\filesystem`

and `wpath` is no longer there.

It used to be defined as:

`typedef basic_path<wstring, wpath_traits> wpath;`

what happened?

Comment: What namespace are you trying to use? It's now in `std::experimental::filesystem`.

Comment: [This MSDN `<filesystem>` reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh874694%28v=vs.140%29.aspx) tells you where it is.

Comment: Tried both `std::experimental::filesystem` & `std::tr2::sys`. `path` exists in bothe but not `wpath`

Comment: My code consists of dozens of projects and hundreds of source files using `wpath` countless time. It compiles and works in VS12 AND VS13.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you see [this MSDN `<filesystem>` reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh874694%28v=vs.140%29.aspx), you will see that it mentions "(V3)", meaning it is based on the [Boost filesystem version 3 API](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm) (which is what the upcoming C++ standard will use as base) which doesn't have e.g. `basic_path` or `wpath`, instead there is only the [`path`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh874769.aspx) class.

If you want to get a string from the path, you use e.g. [`path::wstring`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh874769.aspx#Anchor_46) to get a wide-character string of the path.

Also see [this generic filesystem reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs).